# How should OSMDroid main.xml map view look?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

**Warning**: Noob alert.

I am very new to both Android and OSM.  All I want is a map to display.

Google's MapView can be the root of main.xml, can OSM's MapView be root as well?

**Here is my current main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tilesource="MapquestOSM" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my Activity:**

```
public class AndroidManiTestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.map);
    }
}
```

**I get the following error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anny/com.anny.AndroidManiTestActivity}: 

Android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050000 type #0x12 is not valid
```

**EDIT**:
I am running osmdroid 3.0.8 and slf4j 1.5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setContentView(.. ) needs to take a .layout argument not a .id, so it's

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

after that you can then refer to the .map with a line such as:

```
findViewById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also fixed my libs folder as well so that the jars were referenced properly.